# TSlint return promise string array

Tags: typescript, promise, return-type, tslint

How do I make a function return a promise-string-array?

```
  this.MyArray= [];

  async OtherFunction() {
    this.MyArray= await this.callQuery(); //***
  }

  async callQuery() {
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpclient.get('').subscribe(response => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  }
```

In this example, my tslint is throwing an error over the `this.MyArray` in the link with the `//***`. The error says: `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'any[]`. But when add a type declaration to the `callQuery()` function like this:

`async callQuery(pQuery): string[] {`

then I get a tslint error over `string[]` saying: `Type 'string[]' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value`.

All I am trying to get right is to remove the tslint error over the `this.MyArray` like I explained in the first paragraph. I assume the way to fix this is to have `callQuery()` return an array, but I don't know how to get this working without tslint complaining.

*Note: My callQuery() function will always return an array. So the code is working correctly, it is just tslint that is giving me errors.*

Comment: Sidenote: Both `async` and `await` in/for `callQuery()` could be removed as they basically have no effect. Your waiting for an async result in form of a promise, just to wrap it in promise again. You could just return the original promise and have the same effect.

Comment: @Sirko Thank you Sirko! :) Clearly wasn't understanding what I was doing there haha

Answer (score 3):

If you specifically want to return string[], you will need to return the promise with a generic type (in this case string[]).

Also like Sirko has said, using async/await will have no effect when you're already creating a new promise.

```
callQuery(): Promise<string[]> {
    ...handlePromise
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :) My problem was the async & await. Because when you put them in then Promise<string[]> still gives an error.